# how to share classes and functionality between two applications

Tags: c#, architecture, software-design

I've developed an application (for example's sake, let's say it's a membership card app),
where the user swipes their membership card and the application retrieves their details, finds their shopping history, calculates what discount rate they deserve etc.
The application also does 'rule matching': determining the discount rate according to different rules based on seniority, bank balance etc.

Now I've been asked to create a new module / application wherin the user swipes their card and the system then displays some promotional info according to rule matching (i.e jewlery commercial if your bank balance is > 5,000$, or commercial for customized lisence plates if your listed profession is 'm.d.' etc.).

Now, the two apps are only related in a sense that:
* they use some of the same domain model (the `Member` entity)
* they share some of the same functionality (retrieving member info from card details, rule matching and management of rules)
* the commercial app needs to retrieve information from the main app (Member details)
* also, i'd like 'infrastructure' operations i've developed for my application to be available to the commercials app (like logging capability of `ControllerBase`, or an `httpModule` which manages session creation and destruction- session-per-request).

my existing application is a (fairly) simple MVC / n-tier application.

My best idea so far as to how to approach this, is to have the commercials application as a totaly different application, which communicates with the main application (using wcf/ web services) in order to retrieve members' details.

I also want to have some common classes (like `Member` or `ControllerBase`) shared accross the two applications.
To achieve this, the simplest way would be to create a `Common` dll which will contain anything i'd like to share.
but my concern in that case is that the `Common` dll would just turn into a mish-mash of odds and ends without any coherent relationship (`EntityBase` and `ControllerBase` and `ViewBase` in the same dll??)
any thoughts about the above mentioned solution, or on the subject in general are welcome.

p.s. it shouldn't really matter, but technologies i'm using are c# 3.5 (soon to be 4.0), nHibernate for persistance, winforms apps for the terminals where customers scan their cards and a jQuery-based website for administration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right to have concerns about using one common dll as it could well turn in to a mess very quickly.  I'd suggest using multiple shared dlls (as few or as many as you see fit), split logically.  You'll end up with more projects and references but I don't see that as a problem.